# Is Bitcoin's value the same, country to country? If not, which valuation is correct?

Tags: exchanges

Does a bitcoin have the same value in every country? Is it not like real money that we use in real life? Does it have a different value in every country?

Comment: Define "correct valuation"

Answer (score 2):

Things only have value if you can get stuff with it.  The value of a bitcoin is dependent on supply and demand and how much the BTC-currency exchanges are exchanging for, so it does not necessarily have the same value in a all countries.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic assumption that "real money" always has the same value is not really valid. A million dollars is worth a lot more to me than it is to Bill Gates. And it might be worth nothing on a lifeboat in the middle of the ocean.

A Bitcoin behaves like any other commodity. Its value may be different from person to person or area to area based on things like supply and demand.

So long as transaction costs are low, values will be approximately the same under all reasonable conditions because of exchange and arbitrage. Someone who can get a bitcoin for less than other people will sell it to someone willing to pay more, this will take the people willing to sell for less or buy for more out of the market.

Generally, when you find a significant different in the value of a bitcoin in different places, it's explained by some difference in the asset on the other side. For example, at one time, there was a glut of dollars at an exchange called Mt. Gox. This made a dollar at Mt. Gox worth less than a dollar, and bitcoins sold for more of them at Mt. Gox.

Answer (score 0):

The primary explanation for discrepancies in bitcoin price across different exchanges is the fact that, as a decentralized digital currency, there is no standard or global bitcoin price at any given period of time. It isn't pegged to the USD or to any other fiat currency, nor is it linked to a particular country or to an exchange. As with commodities of all types, supply and demand vary depending upon the time and the market, and the price of bitcoin fluctuates as a result

Comment: This has nothing to do with decentralization. Arbitrage exists in all markets. It's just more apparent in Bitcoin by being a relatively small market.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty much the same everywhere.  You might get a small lag between exchanges around the world but minutes at most.